# A lot of database migrations in the spring project

Tags: java, spring, testing, liquibase

I 'm having a project with more than 50 liquibase migrations.
 
I have tables: Currencies, Countries ... And they are filling in the migrations right now.
The problem is that for each integration test where context is running I have to do all of my 50 migrations. It takes time. And as you know spring is not the fastest framework.
What can I do? The time Gradle is spending for passing all tests is 10 minutes.

Of course, you may say it is the monolith, yes, it is but the customer doesn't want to split up logic because the average level of the team is quite low.

How can I speed up my integration tests?

Comment: Spring is quite fast, executing SQL takes time and there is nothing Spring (or liquibase) can do to help you. Also do you really need to have Spring for all the tests, or are you just being lazy and use `@SpringBootTest` (or the likes) for each and every test (or at least too many tests). I would strongly suggest to take a look at your tests and check if you really need to use Spring in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the kind of migrations, they may not be an actual performance issue. I'm looking at about 130 migrations in one project at the moment, and while they do take a certain amount of time, it's nothing compared to the time it takes to set up and tear down the test context. Starting from a clean slate I'd expect it to shave off maybe 10-20 seconds at best.

It may make sense to restart for other reasons though. For example we have changesets from 2015 that are rolled back in other changesets, so they're just extra clutter. The [documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html) isn't very specific about it, but you can remove all changesets and start from the beginning in the middle of a project. However you need to be careful that you then know what the *correct state* of the database is (without any new changesets you might make). As mentioned in the docs, it usually means the state of the production database.

But remember, this does not guarantee a significant speed-up.